# Markov Chain + Decoding algorithm

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

I am ready a paper [Canteaut and Chabaud](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/Publications/Canteaut_Chabaud98.pdf), I don't get understand the values of transition matrix $P$, in the Proposition 4. If, anybody read this paper please help me understand this values: $P_{u,u}$, $P_{u,u-1}$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$P_{u,v}$ is the probability of a transition between state $u$ to state $v$. It's described more formally in Definition 3 where for a given Markov chain $X$, the conditional probability $P(X_i = v | X_{i-1} = u) = P_{u,v}$.

Comment: thanks by your response, but is just this that I don't uderstand for example Why $$P_{u,u}=\dfrac{k-u}{k}\times \dfrac{n-k-(w-u)}{n-k}+\dfrac{u}{k}\times \dfrac{w-u}{n-k}$$